# How to fix `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dotnet

Trying to compile dotnet code on ubuntu and get this error:

Failed to load /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.109/host/fxr/6.0.9/libhostfxr.so, error: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.109/host/fxr/6.0.9/libhostfxr.so)
The library libhostfxr.so was found, but loading it from /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.109/host/fxr/6.0.9/libhostfxr.so failed

- Installing .NET prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2063370

dotnet --version and dotnet --info do not work.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be linking `/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6` instead of the system's `libstdc++.so.6`?

Comment: I did not link anything. I have this error and I can not use dotnet 6. What do I need to do?

Comment: How did you install dotnet6 on your system?  I just followed through the installation steps for 22.04 in the link that you shared in your question and it worked fine on my system.

Comment: I believe that I use the script here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install
I am not sure though. It was working fine until I did one of ubuntu's system updates.

Comment: That installer only covers up to 18.04, so it may not have installed the correct version into your installation.  You might need to install the dotnet from the repos by following the installation steps at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu  But you will probably need to remove the existing installation by running `dpkg -l | grep dotnet` then doing `sudo apt remove <dotnetname>` listed by dpkg.

Answer (score 0):

Update your repositories and install [build-essential](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/build-essential), which contains GCC, *inter alia*:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

This package depends on `g++`, which depends on `g++-11`, which depends on `libstdc++-11-dev`, which depends on `libstdc++6`, the package you desire.

You should have thus installed a shared object of the GNU standard C++ library at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`. Run the following commands to see the supported versions and which version it points to:

```bash
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Update the symbolic link as needed. Install an older version of the GCC toolchain if necessary. Godspeed.

Originally posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73836387/how-to-fix-glibcxx-3-4-30-not-found-in-ubuntu-22-04