/usr/sbin/mariadbd: /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found
Note
I have studied other posts about this error, but they didn't help me. So, I'm going to describe my problem here.
Starting MariaDB
Following this guide to install WordPress on an Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS server. I installed MariaDB and started it:
sudo systemctl restart mariadb.service

Throws failure error. Then sudo journalctl -xeu mariadb.service shows:

/usr/sbin/mariadbd: /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found

But GLIBCXX_3.4.30 is available
Inspired by this post:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1458100/507217
I run strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX and I get:
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH

So, GLIBCXX_3.4.30 is actually available.
I run ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 and I get:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.30

Question
Everything looks fine. So, what's the problem?
I expected installing and starting MariaDB to be much more smoother than this :(

Investigate
Having gotten some hints from AI chatbots, I noticed that MariaDL is loading /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6, so I did:
ls -lh /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6

And I get this symbolic link to an older version:
/usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.29

Solution
I had to force update the symbolic link to the newer version:
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6

I'm not sure if this force update will break anything else on the server :(
